# Starting out: how much should I charge for a photoshoot?

Tags: business, pricing, professional

I'm in the midst of creating my own small photography business. I've done photoshoots for friends and family, free of charge because I was getting practice. I don't want to overcharge but I don't want to miss out on money. I have backdrops and a few props. How much should I charge for a photoshoot?

Comment: If you're charging for your service you're a professional, not an amateur.

Comment: At the very least, you're going to have to give some sort of indication of where the the world you're based; there's going to be a big difference being doing this is Norway and in the Central African Republic.

Comment: Slightly less than the competition.

Comment: Or twice the competition's price and market it as exclusively available to only the well heeled.